# How can I create ViewModel containing DAO object in Dager 2?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, dagger-2

I create android ViewModel in Activity:

```
EventViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EventViewModel.class);
```

For this I create `EventViewModel` :

```
public class EventViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final EventDao eventDao;

    public EventViewModel(EventDao eventDao) {
        this.eventDao = eventDao;
    }

    public void createEvent(final Event event) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                eventDao.insert(event);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

I learned that I must create custom factory in order to inject my `EventDao` to `EventViewModel`. Ok, let's say i did it.

```
public class ViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private final EventDao eventDao;

    @Inject
    public ViewModelFactory(EventDao eventDao) {
        this.eventDao = eventDao;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass == EventViewModel.class) {
            return (T) new EventViewModel(eventDao);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

but what to do next? I see several ways. If belive to examples from google I must do next in MyActivity:

```
EventViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new ModelFactory(eventDao)).get(EventViewModel.class);
```

1) But where do i get `eventDao` in MyActivity?

2) Do I need create custom `ModelFactory` for each `ViewModel` if it use dao class in?

I use `Dagger 2` and I just want understand how can I create `ViewModel` with DAO and use this `ViewModel` in MyActivity?

Comment: You can create `DatabaseModule` class and provide dao from that class. So You just need to @Injet the Dao in your activity

Comment: Please add the code for your Component which you are trying to configure with `@Inject`

Answer (score 0):

You inject ViewModelFactory in the activity. ViewModelFactory will get EventDao through constructor injection. You pass the injected ViewModelFactory instance say **viewModelFactory** to ViewModelProviders

`EventViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(EventViewModel.class);`